# Dynamically creating variables using the object key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Here is the code :

```
let box = {   
        aaa:111,
        bbb:222,
        ccc:333,
        destruct: function() { 
                   let des = ( {bbb} = box);
                   return des; 
                }
};
   

box.destruct();
aaa // return error : aaa is not defined
bbb // return 222
```

While i could use this syntax `let {aaa,bbb,ccc} = box`  which is great. There would be a case in the future where another pair of keys and values would be added inside the object, for example `ddd : 444, eee:555`. Thus the coding in `destruct : function().....` had to be updated too.

I would like to improve the object destructuring coding by using `eval()` and `Object.keys().join()`. This is the far i can go

```
        destruct : function() { 
                    let str = Object.keys( box ).join(); // "aaa,bbb,ccc"
                    let des = eval( "{" + str + "} = box" );
                    return des;
}

box.destruct() // return Unexpected token '='
```

Comment: I don't think your first code works...?

Comment: how about `return Object.assign({}, this);`

Comment: what do you want from the `destruct` method - the values of all the keys of your `box` object? why not just use `Object.values(box)`?

Comment: This seems like a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I understand the ideia but I'm not sure if that would be nice because you wouldn't know the variable names for the object.

Comment: hi @apple apple, let des = (**let** {bbb} = box) that let statement shouldn't be there. I've corrected it. Sorry

Comment: @iamaatoh, the idea is to access functions (or any keys & value) inside the object without using Object.keys, Object.values, or dot / bracket notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the keys to `window` object

```js
let box = {
  aaa: 111,
  bbb: 222,
  ccc: 333,
  destruct: function () {
    Object.assign(window, this, {destruct: undefined})
  },
};

box.destruct();

console.log(aaa, bbb, ccc);
```

```js
let box = {
  aaa: 111,
  bbb: 222,
  ccc: 333,
  destruct: function () {
    for (key in this) {
      if (key == 'destruct') continue 
      window[key] = this[key]
    }
  },
};

box.destruct();

console.log(aaa, bbb, ccc);
```

Comment: Thanks! Never thought about assigning to window before. Seems neat too!

Answer (score 0):

So from the question, it seems like you are trying to **dynamically** create **variables** at **run time** using the object `box` key values, while you shouldn't be doing this. But if its the last option then you should do something like this below.

```js
let box = {
  aaa: 111,
  bbb: 222,
  ccc: 333,
  destruct: function () {
    for (key in box) {
      eval(`${key} = ${box[key]}`);
    }
  },
};

box.destruct();

console.log(aaa, bbb, ccc);
```

Comment: _"...while you shouldn't be doing this."_ 
why? is it because of the eval()? or the whole idea itself?

Comment: you can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea , and also using this approach creates global variables which may override other important variables if not taken care of.

Comment: Thanks! Will keep it my mind about the global variables. Maybe i will resort to fancy variable naming for time being.